# Absolute positioning breaks when other flex items on the same row have different heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Absolute positioning breaks when another flex item on the same row has a varying height.

[image: Here's a picture of the issue]

The read more button should be positioned like on the first card (titled 'Sky High WiFi'). Because the article description is shorter on the second card, it's causing the read more button to move up.

In the code below, how can I prevent absolute positioning from "breaking" when two children on the same row have varying heights?

```css
  a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff8a64;
}

.author-name {
  display: inline;
}

.author-name-date-padding {
  padding: 0 .4rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: montserrat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.6rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.post-meta-and-title {
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem 0;
}

.post-meta {
  font-size: .7rem;
}

.post-title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.post-description {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.5rem 2rem;
}

.btn {
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, #ffb064 -1%, #ff6496 101%);
  position: absolute;
  right: -1rem;
  bottom: -1rem;
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: white;
  font-size: .9rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE STYLES */

@media (min-width: 810px) {
  .container {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  article {
    width: calc(50% - 4rem);
  }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    article {
      width: calc(33.3% - 4rem);
    }
  }
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <article>
    <header class="post-meta-and-title">
      <div class="post-meta">
        <time datetime="2019-05-09 20:00">May 9, 2019</time>
        <p class="author-name"><span class="author-name-date-padding">|</span>
          <a href="https://carney.co/author/adamkunes/" rel="author">Craig Kleila</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2><a class="post-title" href="#">Sky High WiFi</a></h2>
    </header>

    <p class="post-description">plus – better landing pages, heatmaps, and Starbucks.</p>

    <footer>
      <a href="#" class="btn">READ MORE</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article>
    <header class="post-meta-and-title">
      <div class="post-meta">
        <time datetime="2019-05-05 12:00">May 5, 2019</time>
        <p class="author-name"><span class="author-name-date-padding">|</span>
          <a href="https://carney.co/author/adamkunes/" rel="author">Mallorie Beckner</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2><a class="post-title" href="#">Are you afraid of clowns?</a></h2>
    </header>

    <p class="post-description">plus – tech overload, productivity, and Tom Brady.</p>

    <footer>
      <a href="#" class="btn">READ MORE</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article>
    <header class="post-meta-and-title">
      <div class="post-meta">
        <time datetime="2019-05-01 18:00">May 1, 2019</time>
        <p class="author-name"><span class="author-name-date-padding">|</span>
          <a href="https://carney.co/author/adamkunes/" rel="author">Nick Ferrentino</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2><a class="post-title" href="#">It's time to get real folks</a></h2>
    </header>

    <p class="post-description">plus – sell more event tickets, and faster feedback.</p>

    <footer>
      <a href="#" class="btn">READ MORE</a>
    </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Is this sample code supposed to break? it looks like what you wanted, except you missed the closing article tag on the last article

Comment: maybe not relevant, but here is a solution *without* absolute positioning and using a *column flexbox* only - see https://jsfiddle.net/yhekgo0u/

Answer (score 1):

Just make `article` position relative instead of footer

The break is caused the fact that your footer is always right after your content but when some box has more content, their footer is lower in their box so when you are positioning your button based on the footer, it won't work. The flex item (article) stretches but the content inside just stacks like normal so the footer isn't at the bottom of the box. By making article(flex item) relative, you are ensuring that the height of the boxes are the same since it is stretched by default and your button will always appear at the same spot.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff8a64;
}

.author-name {
  display: inline;
}

.author-name-date-padding {
  padding: 0 .4rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: montserrat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.6rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.post-meta-and-title {
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem 0;
}

.post-meta {
  font-size: .7rem;
}

.post-title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.post-description {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

footer {
  padding: 0 1.5rem 2rem;
}

.btn {
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, #ffb064 -1%, #ff6496 101%);
  position: absolute;
  right: -1rem;
  bottom: -1rem;
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: white;
  font-size: .9rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE STYLES */

@media (min-width: 810px) {
  .container {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  article {
    width: calc(50% - 4rem);
  }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    article {
      width: calc(33.3% - 4rem);
    }
  }
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <article>
    <header class="post-meta-and-title">
      <div class="post-meta">
        <time datetime="2019-05-09 20:00">May 9, 2019</time>
        <p class="author-name"><span class="author-name-date-padding">|</span>
          <a href="https://carney.co/author/adamkunes/" rel="author">Craig Kleila</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2><a class="post-title" href="#">Sky High WiFi</a></h2>
    </header>

    <p class="post-description">plus – better landing pages, heatmaps, and Starbucks.</p>

    <footer>
      <a href="#" class="btn">READ MORE</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article>
    <header class="post-meta-and-title">
      <div class="post-meta">
        <time datetime="2019-05-05 12:00">May 5, 2019</time>
        <p class="author-name"><span class="author-name-date-padding">|</span>
          <a href="https://carney.co/author/adamkunes/" rel="author">Mallorie Beckner</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2><a class="post-title" href="#">Are you afraid of clowns?</a></h2>
    </header>

    <p class="post-description">plus – tech overload, productivity, and Tom Brady.</p>

    <footer>
      <a href="#" class="btn">READ MORE</a>
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article>
    <header class="post-meta-and-title">
      <div class="post-meta">
        <time datetime="2019-05-01 18:00">May 1, 2019</time>
        <p class="author-name"><span class="author-name-date-padding">|</span>
          <a href="https://carney.co/author/adamkunes/" rel="author">Nick Ferrentino</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2><a class="post-title" href="#">It's time to get real folks</a></h2>
    </header>

    <p class="post-description">plus – dsf dsfdsafa sdf adsf asdf asdf sdafa sf dsaf sdf dsaf dsaf asfd dsf sdf dfsell more event tickets, and faster feedback.</p>

    <footer>
      <a href="#" class="btn">READ MORE</a>
    </footer>
  </article>
</section>
```

You can run the coe above, then press the full screen button to see the actual result you are looking for since it is stacked in default view

Answer (score 1):

This might be the solution you are looking for: https://codepen.io/mgrace/pen/RmGeqm.

namely: 
`article {
position: relative;
}` instead of

`footer {
position: relative;
}`

and instead `footer` is absolutely position in relation to the `article` instead of the button being absolutely positioned  to the `footer`. Since in your existing code the height of the footer is being affected by the length of text within the article body and the button being absolutely positioned in relation to the footer. This change instead sets the position of the footer based on the article container instead, thus ensuring that it is always set to that bottom right corner.